# Resolving Mercurial Case-Folding Collision in Windows

Tags: mercurial

I've seen the other Mercurial case-folding Answers on StackOverflow - they say that if you have access to a case sensitive file system like unix then check out there and it should fix it.  Problem is, I don't have access to a unix box, I'm a windows developer developing a windows application.

How do I fix this without a Unix box?

Comment: You could install Linux in a virtual machine, e.g. VirtualBox with an Ubuntu install.

Comment: Thats a lot of work to resolve an issue that was caused by a trivial task like renaming a file!

Comment: As far as I know recent versions of Mercurial should have built-in safeguards against case folding collisions...

Comment: We're using a recent version of Mercurial on Windows and still saw the error.

Comment: 2015. Cannot rename a file to correct casing. What a joke of a source control system.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is a `filesystem` help topic being worked on that will be included in the next version of Mercurial:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2012-April/039522.html

> **Renaming colliding files**
>
> On case-insensitive filesystems, updating to revisions which have
>   files with case collisions will abort, even with
>   `--check` or `--clean`.
>
> To repair such revisions, you should give new names to one or both of
>   the colliding files on a case-sensitive filesystem, and commit them to
>   create new collision safe revision.
>
> .. note::
>      If you want to (or need to) browse or repair such
>      revisions on case-insensitive filesystems, please see 'Updating
>      manually' section.
>
> If :hg:`merge` is aborted, but :hg:`update --check` to each
>   revisions successes, collision occurs between revision to be merged.
>
> In this case, files in one of them or both should be renamed to avoid
>   collision before merging.
>
> With recent Mercurial, you can change case of filename safely in steps
>   below, even on case-insensitive filesystems::
>
> ```
> $ hg rename a.txt tmp
> $ hg rename tmp A.TXT
> ```
>
> **Updating manually**
>
> If you want to (or need to) update working directory by the
>   revision causing case-folding collision on case-insensitive
>   filesystems, to rename colliding files or browsing contents at such
>   revision for example, please see the Wiki page below::
>
> https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ManualCheckout
>
> This is NOT recommended for non expert Mercurial users.

Another similar manual method is described here:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FixingCaseCollisions

This also dives rather deep into Mercurial internals though, so you should avoid it unless as a last resort.

Comment: I had to use the method described in http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FixingCaseCollisions

Though i didn't need to do the clone first.

Comment: "With recent Mercurial, you can change case of filename safely in steps below, even on case-insensitive filesystems::" - that is if you know about the problem before checking stuff in, in other words recent Mercurial still has this bug effectively unsolved.

Comment: Why do you say there is a bug? Case-sensitive file systems exist and Mercurial supports them. When adding a file with a case folding conflict on a case-sensitive system, Mercurial will explicitly warn you about it. If you decide to ignore the warning and commit it anyway, then yes you’ve introduced a case collision, and you can recover from it as described above.

Comment: Just ran into that issue (with Mercurial-3.5+5) and @MattVukomanovic link worked for me as well

Comment: @MattVukomanovic your link is now at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FixingCaseCollisions

Comment: With the latest version of mercurial, you don't have to do a rename to some temporariy filename first. I just tried `hg rename a.txt A.TXT` and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 14):

We resolved this without resorting to a case-sensitive filesystem by issuing HG rename commands.  Say you are having trouble because "Foo.txt" needs to be called "foo.txt":

```
hg rename Foo.txt Foo.txt.renamed
hg rename Foo.txt.renamed foo.txt
```

We encountered this problem when a file was deleted and then later re-created in the main repository with the same name, but different case.  A branch repository that was created before these changes could not then be merged in, despite the changesets from the main repository having been pulled.

Answer (score 3):

To get a case folding issue on windows I'm guessing that you've got the differing cases in different branches or heads in the repo, and it becomes a problem when merging.  I can't see how (on Windows) you would actually get two different cases in the same revision without going via a unix box.

So, if they are in different revisions then you can do something like this:

```
hg update <some rev>
hg remove -A -f "Some File"
```

then the merge would succeed ok.  The -A is for 'after', and the -f will 'force'.

Answer (score 3):

Its a regular problem in Windows for not using *case-sensitive* file systems. If you want to do it with the `TortoiseHg Workbench` installed, search the file and rename it:

right click/TortoiseHg/Rename File

It will rename the file to the right case sensitive name you want. The next picture shows how i changed `XMLConverter` for `XmlConverter`

[image]

Then in the Workbench you may commit the file change:

[image]

> This was updated a week later

The solution presented may gives you problems later updating the whole repository from another PC. So the ultimate way to resolve it, may be making 2 commits:

1. One for renaming files with the unwanted name to some temporary one.
   Ex.: *XMLConverter2*
2. Another for renaming the temporary files to the new names. Ex.: *XmlConverter*

So it got like this:

[image: renaming the temporary files to the new names]

This is actually the way it doesnt make conflicts in Windows anymore. It looks ugly but it is effective.

Comment: If you do two commits are they any issues rebase collapsing them back together?

Comment: I have tried yet. If somebody does it please give the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bitbucket.org, you can browse the source on the problem branch, go to the file, click the drop down by edit, rename the file (or in our case rename the directory) commit those changes and pull.

Thank you Bitbucket team!

Answer (score 1):

I solved in a simpler way:

1. List item
2. Cut the renamed folder file and paste it on a temporary location (i.e. Desktop)
3. Commit the "*R*" changes
4. Paste the folder again
5. Commit the "*?*" status

What it's really causing the problem is trying to create and delete at the same time a file/folder that is potentially the same in case unsensitive systems.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue but using a *nix system was not an option. I was able to resolve it following [these instructions](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FixingCaseCollisions).

---

On Windows, it is currently (before Mercurial 1.1) possible to introduce case collisions in the repo that prevent you from checking out a repository.

One way to repair such a repository is to check it out on a case-sensitive Unix system, remove the problematic file, and commit it again.

If that's not possible, you can do the following:

```
hg clone --noupdate repo repair
cd repair
hg debugsetparents <bad revision>
hg debugrebuildstate
```

At this point, Mercurial will think you have the bad revision checked out and all the files are missing (status '!'). To fix the repo, we simply have to do:

```
hg remove --after <file causing the collision>
```

Now hg status should show the troublesome file in state 'R' and all other files in state '!'. Now we can check in our fix:

```
hg commit --message "fix case collision"
```

To get all our files back, we just check out again:

```
hg update tip
```

Reference: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial/2008-June/019921.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but this is what worked for me and I hope it is of use to someone. In my case I had a legacy repo with an old branch I needed to close.

I used to Windows bash shell of Windows 10 to resolve this `lxrun /install` and then when that was setup I installed mercurial `sudo apt-get install mercurial` This will give you access to your file system via the mnt folder, and you can use mercurial from the command line.

In my case I could then easily update to the problematic branch and close it.

Answer (score -1):

As Laurens Holst said renaming the folder/file passing through a temporary file system worked for me.

```
$ hg rename a.txt tmp
$ hg rename tmp A.TXT
```

But to make it work, and avoid colliding files error during merge i had to PURGE after renaming