# How can I get the contents of a particular Mercurial revision when one of the files has an error?

Tags: windows, macos, version-control, mercurial, revision

So I've been coordinating some source code across my office with Mercurial.

Long story short, it looks like I did something completely wrong and screwed up and lost a ton of files on some revision

In any event some amount of investigative work has helped me drill down which revision is where things went wrong and hopefully I can recover some files from that. The problem is that I can't seem to pull that particular revision due to an error:

```
C:\sourcefolder>hg update -r 147
abort: case-folding collision between Files/someStupidFile.png and Files/SomeStupidFile.png
```

This project was coordinated across a Windows machine and a Mac, so that plus some carelessness caused the case folding issue.

I'm aware of case folding issues and I know how to fix them - but that only creates a *new* revision where things are fixed. I don't want that. I want, in this case, **every other file in revision 147**.

How can I tell Mercurial "get everything from 147, ignore any broken files"?

I know that you can get a file listing and I've done that once to try and construct a batch file to get a set of files I needed, but I figure there has *got* to be some better way.

Comment: I think you're going to have to deal with the case folding problem -- search SO for "[mercurial] case folding" for lots of other examples, in particular: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531853/resolving-mercurial-case-folding-collision-in-windows

Comment: How about `hg revert -r REV`? Have you tried to use that?

Comment: "How can I the contents?" I think you accidentally the whole verb.

Comment: You should be able to generate a tarball with hg archive.

Comment: @Helgi: yeah it gives basically the same error.

Comment: @Schnapple: Try `hg revert -r REV -X Files/someStupidFile.png -X ...`, this should exclude the specified files.

Comment: @Ringding that works for what I want. Make it an answer and I'll accept it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just generate a tarball with `hg archive`.