# Changing case of filename in Mercurial on Windows

Tags: windows, version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm using the latest version of Mercurial with TortoiseHg on Windows. Let's say I have 5 branches in my repository that all have a file named `MyFile.txt`. I want to change just the case of this filename in a branch so the new name is `myfile.txt`. Later on when I merge this branch into my other 4 branches, that same file needs to be renamed from `MyFile.txt` to `myfile.txt` with no case-folding collisions. So eventually all branches will be in sync with the new filename `myfile.txt`.

What's the best way to achieve this on Windows?

Edit:
For example, should I first rename `MyFile.txt` to something different like `bla.txt` and then rename `bla.txt` to `myfile.txt`, and if that's the case, should I do the same thing on all 5 branches to avoid case-folding collisions when merging?

Comment: Yes, the easiest fix is to transition through another filename as you've suggested.  It's covered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531853/resolving-mercurial-case-folding-collision-in-windows along with some useful links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Resolving Mercurial Case-Folding Collision in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531853/resolving-mercurial-case-folding-collision-in-windows) for more detailed answers.

I was able to solve my problem by renaming the file to something different such as `temp.txt` and then committing the change, and then renaming back to the original file name with the case change. Merging into other branches worked fine.